# SQL Comma separated string total count

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, count

Schema :

```
SubscriberId NewsletterIdCsv 
------------ --------------- 
1     48,51,94     
2     43,22
3     33,11
4     90,61
```

I Need to get the count for each rows NewsletterIdCsv and then add all of them up to get a total count of all rows, for the basic row count I am doing the following:

```
SELECT newsletteridcsv, len(newsletteridcsv) - len(replace(newsletteridcsv, ',', '')) +1 IndividualCount
FROM DBTABLE
```

This Gives me the Result :

```
NewsletterIdCsv IndividualCount
------------ --------------- 
48,51,94     3
43,22        2
33,11        2
90,61        2
```

How do I get the total count (In this example 9)?

Note : This table has 5 Million records and I do not think using a temp table to Insert count and then finally going through the temp table rows to accumulate the count is an optimized way?
Also I am totally against using cursors for efficiency issues !

What's the best way to get the total count ?

Comment: Can you normalize your data?

Comment: "against using cursors for efficiency issues" and yet the data is structured in a horribly inefficient manner. Curious tradeoff

Comment: @billinkc Since we are anticipating 1.5 billion rows, normalization was already considered, tried and tested and it turned out to be extremely slow, these are just our intermediate tables where we work off to prepare the final data.

Comment: Above comment applies to your comment too @bluefeet

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`SUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to add them together:

```
SELECT SUM(len(newsletteridcsv) - len(replace(newsletteridcsv, ',', '')) +1) 
    AS TotalCount
FROM DBTABLE
```

Since you're just asking for the total count, you don't even need to `GROUP BY` anything.

Answer (score 4):

You've already done the tricky part (len minus commas), now just run a sum of that:

```
SELECT sum(len(newsletteridcsv) - len(replace(newsletteridcsv, ',', '')) +1) as TotalCount
FROM DBTABLE
```

Comment: Thanks, since @LittleBobbyTables replied first I would have to mark that answered :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CountDelimited]
(@Str varchar(8000), @Delimiter varchar(1))
RETURNS int AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result int
if (@Str ='' OR @Str is null)
begin
set @Result = 0
end
else
begin
set @Result = (select SUM(len(@Str) - len(replace(@Str, @Delimiter, '')) +1)) 
end
RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: Can you explain what the code does and how it solves the issue?

Comment: Also  checks for empty or NULL values. Can be used anywhere as function, plus that can be used with any delimited char.

Comment: That would be nice to put those details as [edit] to the answer, ideally also including comments in the code where appropriate